# What is MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE_NOCOALESCE flag in winapi?

Tags: winapi, mouse

> **MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE_NOCOALESCE**
> 0x2000
>    The **WM_MOUSEMOVE** messages will not be coalesced. The default behavior is to coalesce **WM_MOUSEMOVE** messages.

I don't understand this sentence.

```
INPUT input = { 0 };
input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE_NOCOALESCE;
input.mi.mouseData = WHEEL_DELTA * 100;
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

I tried this code but couldn't recognize something like mouse move or mouse click is blocked.

> When the mouse is moved over the client area of a window, the window procedure receives the
> message WM_MOUSEMOVE.

This is a quotation from Programming Windows by Charles Petzold. I think WM_MOUSEMOVE just means mouse was moved. 
What does 'The WM_MOUSEMOVE messages will not be coalesced' mean? 
What happens if WM_MOUSEMOVE messages are coalesced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WM_MOUSEMOVE` is generated on demand. The system will accumulate all mouse movement into a single `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message when the program asks for it. In other words, all input is coalesced into a single message.

Using the `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE_NOCOALESCE` flag allows a client of `SendInput` to inject mouse movement that produces discrete `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages.

Comment: Then after I call SendInput with `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE_NOCOALESCE` flag, that message queue is set always not to coalesce WM_MOUSEMOVE until I call SendInput without `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE_NOCOALESCE` flag?

Comment: I'll have to come up with a sample that illustrates the different behavior. That'll take a while. In the meantime, you can read about the meaning of *"coalesce"* in the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coalesce): *"to unite into a whole"* seems to be the most appropriate definition.